# Add additional functinality to GoTo

Tags: simulink

I would like to add additional functionality to *Goto* block such as:

1. Adapting the name in *GotoTag* in case it is connected
2. Create a *From* block.

For the first point, i placed my script to MoveFcn. I am unhappy from this solution, since i would like *GotoTag* to change once i connect the *Goto* block to another block.

For the second point, i added my script to CopyFnc. Here i am again unhappy from this solution, since i only want to create *From* block and not an additional *GoTo* block.

My question are:

1. Is there a way to update the name of *Goto* block by connection?
2. How could i create only a *From* block using my mouse (or\with an additional Cont\Alt\Tab)?

Answer (score 0):

For point 2, you can use [Create From Blocks](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25736-create-from-blocks) from the File Exchange. Not sure about 1., I can't see any easy way of doing this. Why do you want to do this?